# Include Android platform jars when using javah tool

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, javah

How to include jar files of the Android platform when using the javah tool to create a C/C++ .h header file ???

Comment: How about -classpath argument?

Comment: Actually this is the question, How to include the android platform jars with the -classpath argument ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. your android SDK is installed in C:\android\sdk (and you have downloaded Android 1.5 platform)
2. your android NDK is installed in C:\android\ndk

Open command line window. Go to C:\android\ndk\samples\hello-jni folder. And execute the following:

```
javah -classpath C:\android\sdk\platforms\android-3;src com.example.hellojni.HelloJni
```

It will generate `com_example_hellojni_HelloJni.h` file with JNI functions for hello-jni example from Android NDK.

Comment: Thanks Mārtiņš it worked finally, but after the semi-column I just appended the full directory to the bin folder in my project without any spaces, then the full class name as you said "com.example.hellojni.HelloJni"